# ReactJS: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web

I'm currently working on a messaging application using React and Firebase. I'm using React Hooks for using `state` for storing and channels. The following code is the implementation of that

```
const [channels, setChannels] = useState([]);
```

The following code is for getting the channels from firebase database

```
useEffect(() =>{
 db.collection("channels").onSnapshot((snapshot) => 
    setChannels(
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        channel : doc.data(),
      }))
    )
  );
}, []);
```

And rendering the channels in the page using the following code

```
<div className=".sidebar__channelsList">
  {channels.map(({id , channel }) => (
    <SidebarChannel
      key={id} 
      id={id} 
      channelName={channels.channelName} 
    />
  ))}
</div>
```

SidebarChannel.js

```
function SidebarChannel(id,channelName) {
    return (
      <div className="sidebarChannel">
      <h4>
      <span className="sidebarChannel__hash">#</span>
      {channelName}
    </h4>
  </div>
}
```

So my problem here is i am getting an error while running this code at can't figure out what's the problem in it. The error is

[image]

Comment: Maybe there's a typo? It is not `channels.channelName` but `channel` (with no "s").
I any case the error is quite clear: you are rendering an empty object which is not allowed.

Comment: Nop i just forgot to add some {} in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Destructuring so SidebarChannel component should be:

```
function SidebarChannel({ id, channelName }) {
    return (
      <div className="sidebarChannel">
      <h4>
      <span className="sidebarChannel__hash">#</span>
      {channelName}
    </h4>
  </div>
}
```